# How to show the previous and current result in the opportunity probability in the particular opportunity by using the formula field?

Tags: formula, formula-field, validation-rule

To all,
There is a formula field Stage_Changes_Status_c with return type Text.Here my requirement is following,

Once I select the Opportunity in the stage to the any it's value like in the list of Prospecting to Closed Off it's provide the appropriate probability to it's stage. So It's should be shown as:

```
 "probability changed : 'probability of (selected stage's probability)'%
```

following like an above showed.
When I modified the previous probability value to the  new one, it should be shown like the following,

```
"Probability changed:'probability of (previous selected stage's probability)'% - probability of (current stage's probability)'%"
```

I was trying this task as follows:

```
SUBSTITUTE(
("probability changed : 'probability of a'% - 'probability of b'%"),

(SUBSTITUTE(("probability changed : 'probability of a'% - 'probability of b'%"), 'probability of a', 
TEXT( Probability *100))),

(SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE(("probability changed : 'probability of a'% - 'probability of b'%"), 'probability of a', 
TEXT( Probability *100))),
'probability of b', 
TEXT( Probability *100)))
)
```

Above code is doesn't provide the output and the error also I don't know why so. Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know old and new probability.

1. Create a new percent field (Old Probability)
2. Create a workflow rule (ischange(Probability))
3. Field update on old probability PriorValue(Probability)
4. Then use old and new probability field on formula field.

Comment: thanks for giving idea but in workflow there is no operator like is change so what am I do plz give the suggestion to rectify this problem

Comment: isChanged(Probability ) is works for probability.